# Did Genos have his lastest upgrades when fighting the Deep Sea King in the Virtual Genocide Simulation program?

Tags: one-punch-man

In the One Punch Man audio books,

> Genos fights the Deep Sea King in a program called Virtual Genocide Simulation and he wins

Did Genos have his lastest upgrades when fighting the Deep Sea King in the Virtual Genocide Simulation program?

Comment: You should put your entire question in spoiler tags as it does little good to hide part of it when your unspoiled question is basically what is in the spoiler anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Genos fights the Virtual!Deep Sea King with his G4 upgrades.**

I've based myself on the [wiki page](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Virtual_Genocide_Simulation) for this audio play, which says the simulation happens "sometime after Genos' G4 upgrades and before Genos meets Gouketsu". For reference, Genos is stronger than when he fought G4 (obviously) but weaker than when he fought Elder Centipede.